# Background scrolling with content matching top and bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page with a simple div. If the div is at the top of the page, the background image (a very long vertical wallpaper) should also only be displaying the top section. If we scroll all the way down, then at the last area way at the bottom, the bottom of the background will show. The effect is that it's like a parallax where the scrolling of the content and background image occur in tandem and are scaled to each other.

How would I do this?

Update: My attempt is something like this:

```
function setupMainContent(){
    $("#programming").delay(1000).fadeIn(1000, function(){
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var current = $(window).scrollTop();
            var bottom = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
            var scale = 100*(current/bottom);
            $('body').css({
                'background-position':scale+'%'
            });
        });
}
```

I don't really know how to work with variables within quotes however.

Update: I got it to work using this:

```
function setupMainContent(){
    $("#programming").delay(1000).fadeIn(1000, function(){
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var current = $(window).scrollTop();
            var bottom = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
            var scale = 100*(current/bottom) + "%";
            document.body.style.backgroundPosition = "center " + scale;
        });
    });
}
```

But there seems to be very bad impact on performance. Is there any way to make it more responsive and faster?

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment

Comment: If you apply this CSS to the div, the part of the image that will show as the div's background will change as the div moves down the page.  If this is not what you intended, please clarify the behavior you are seeking.

Comment: The page has a background-image (not the div) that is about 500px high. There is a div on the page that is, say, 1000px high. When we scroll the page, the div and backround image will scroll in tandem such that: When we are the top of the div, we see the top of the background image. When we are the bottom of the div, we will see the bottom of the background image.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
function setupMainContent(){
$("#programming").delay(1000).fadeIn(1000, function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var current = $(window).scrollTop();
        var bottom = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
        var scale = 100*(current/bottom) + "%";
        document.body.style.backgroundPosition = "center " + scale;
    });
    */
});
}
```